# Stability of an ODE System with a Periodic Forcing Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

Suppose that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \rho$ and $\kappa$ are non-negative constants and define $f(t) \geq 0$ to be some forcing function. I have been struggling to get some insight into the following non-linear, first-order, system of differential equations.
\begin{align*}
x'(t) & = f(t) + \alpha \, y(t) - \beta \, x(t), \\
y'(t) & = \gamma \, x(t) - \alpha \, y(t) + \rho \,y(t)\left(1-\frac{y(t)}{\kappa}\right).
\end{align*}
So far, I can show that if $f(t) = a \geq 0$, a stable asymptotic equilibrium point exists. Otherwise, I have been looking at $f(t)=\sin(t)$. Plots show that the system approaches a stable periodic orbit but I am not sure how to show this mathematically. Obviously, if there is a way to obtain a closed-form expression for $\left(x(t),y(t)\right)$ that would be ideal but I am not sure that's possible.

If anyone could provide some insight into how to show that as $t \to \infty$, the system for $f(t)=\sin(t)$ tends to a periodic orbit I would be extremely grateful. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this system as a linear system $(\rho = 0)$. On those conditions, the stability is governed by the eigenvalues of $M = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\beta & \alpha \\
 \gamma & -\alpha \\
\end{array}
\right)$ which are $\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{(\alpha -\beta )^2+4 \alpha  \gamma }+\alpha +\beta \right),\frac{1}{2}
   \left(\sqrt{(\alpha -\beta )^2+4 \alpha  \gamma }-\alpha -\beta \right)\right\}$. Now if for instance $\alpha=2,\beta = -1,\gamma = -\frac{17}{16}$ both eigenvalues are negative so the homogeneous response goes to zero remaining the forced response describing a periodic orbit after a transient. Incorporating now the nonlinear term $\rho y\left(1-\frac{y}{\kappa}\right)$ the linear theory doesn't help. Perhaps for very small $\rho$. Concluding, this system is nonlinear and depends on $\alpha,\beta, \gamma,\rho,\kappa$ parameters. General considerations are hard to establish. The best way to study is dividing to conquer.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for responding! So in the spirit you suggested, does this make sense? Consider
\begin{align*}
\gamma x'(t) + \beta y'(t) = \gamma f(t) + \alpha (\gamma -\beta + \beta \rho)y(t) - \frac{\beta \rho}{k} y(t)^2.
\end{align*}
When $x'(t) = y'(t) = 0$, $y(t)$ can be obtained by solving a quadratic equation and is periodic provided $f(t)\geq 0 $ and is chosen appropriately, i.e., it is periodic. Plugging this into the first equation, we see that when $x'(t)=0$, $x(t)$ is the sum of two periodic functions. Thus, on the nullclines, we observe periodicity?

Comment: When $x'(t) = 0, y'(t)=0$ the found relationship $y(t) = \phi(f(t))$ doesn't makes sense because then $y'(t)\ne 0$. The stability in nonlinear systems with a forcing function involved can be quite complex.

Comment: I apologize. You are definitely correct, I didn't explain myself clearly. Basically, I was thinking of representing the 3-D non-autonomous problem as a 4-D autonomous one by replacing the forcing term with $f(\theta)$ and then adding another differential equation $\theta'(t)=1$. Then, by looking at the solutions in phase space when $x'(t) = y'(t)=0$ while varying $\theta$, the periodicity becomes apparent. That is, for every isocline, $x'(t) = y'(t)=C$ where $C$ is some constant, the dynamics of $q(t)$ and $x(t)$ are periodic with respect to $\theta$.